# return list all the procedures, tables and functions in my databse

Tags: sql-server

I want sql query which will return list all the procedures, tables and functions in my database
I tried following query for procedures but not work

```
SELECT NAME FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type='P'
```

Comment: Why not just query sys.procedures? Anyway, your query is correct so what does "not work" mean? Although you might want to add `and objectpropertyex(object_id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0` to filter out system procedures.

Answer (score 1):

To return all the procedures(except system procedures), the query is:-

```
select * from DBName.information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

For all functions you can use

```
SELECT name AS function_name
,type_desc
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';
```

For all the tables, the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```